# Remove selective additional namespace from selective nodes in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Thanks to Stack Overflow and @michael.hor257k I was able to update namespaces successfully in my XML Document.

Now, there is only one problem.
My SAP System couldn't understand a couple of fields from XSD and thus added its own namespace to accommodate to the XML Schema.

This is solvable through SAP, but we don't have that software(SPROXY) installed yet.

So, I have to achieve this using XSLT 1.0.

My original XML was:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<n0:eCPR xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:DV4:/1SAI/TAS1F59A417878D36573F1D:700:2013/05/24" xmlns:n0="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">

<n0:employees>
  <n0:employee>
    <n0:name id="20019768">Paul John</n0:name>
</n0:employee>
</n0:employees>
</n0:eCPR>
```

And the XSLT Used to achieve the required output below:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="CPR:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

After updating with the current namespace my XML(Where the error is) Looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CPR:eCPR xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
 <CPR:projectInfo>
  <CPR:awardingBody xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" asx:root=""/>
  <CPR:contractAgencyID xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" asx:root=""/>
  <CPR:contractAgency/>
  <CPR:projectName xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" asx:root=""/>
  <CPR:projectID/>
  <CPR:awardingBodyID/>
  <CPR:projectNum/>
  <CPR:contractID/>
```

So, the nodes `awardingBody`,`contractAgencyID` and `Project Name` are the fields which couldn't got properly converted by the system.( The nodes with `xmlns:asx` namespace  )

I need to remove these namespaces. Is it possible through XSLT. Condition: Remove namespace of only those entries whose namespace is http://www.sap.com/abapxml or I can provide a name of nodes(as they are fixed)

What the ideal structure should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CPR:eCPR xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
 <CPR:projectInfo>
  <CPR:awardingBody/>
  <CPR:contractAgencyID />
  <CPR:contractAgency/>
  <CPR:projectName/>
  <CPR:projectID/>
  <CPR:awardingBodyID/>
  <CPR:projectNum/>
  <CPR:contractID/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay XSLT 1.0

Comment: This is very confusing. Is the first XML the input to the transformation? Based on your previous 2 questions on this, I suspect it is the output. Please show the input or clarify.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, after your help, i was able to product the first XML. Now, i wanted the first XML to be the input. But, we can use the original XML also. I will update the post with original XML and current XSLT which will help you

Comment: Please show the original XML that produces the output you show us. The one that has the `awardingBody`, `contractAgencyID` and `Project Name` elements with the `root` attribute. The input you show us could not produce the output you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) that your original XML actually looks something like this:

**XML**

```
<n0:eCPR xmlns:n0="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd" xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml">
    <n0:projectInfo>
        <n0:awardingBody asx:root=""/>
        <n0:contractAgencyID asx:root=""/>
        <n0:contractAgency/>
        <n0:projectName asx:root=""/>
        <n0:projectID/>
        <n0:awardingBodyID/>
        <n0:projectNum/>
        <n0:contractID/>
    </n0:projectInfo>
</n0:eCPR>
```

In order to get the requested output - i.e. without copying the `asx:root` attributes - you need to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:CPR="http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/CPR-Prod-Test/CPR.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="CPR:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(namespace-uri()='http://www.sap.com/abapxml')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or perhaps do:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(namespace-uri())]"/>
```

to remove *any* attributes that aren't in no-namespace.

Comment: @micheal Perfect.. The whole problem is fixed. Thanks for all your replies and clarifications.